# tcl sed with variable

Tags: linux, sed, tcl

hi I try sed command in tcl
but there's something misunderstanding

i do a for loop to run the sed command,
the item of list is actually in the file (is read from the file)
but there're nothing to be replaced

and i also puts the variable to check if the item are wrong,
but the targets are all what i want

how can i modify my sed command

`for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $moduleList]} {incr i} {
        set mTarget [lindex $moduleList $i]
        puts $mTarget
        set mReplace [lindex $moduleReplaceList $i]
        #puts $mReplace
        exec sed -i {s/$mTarget/$mReplace/g} $verilog_new 
    }`

i find a workaround is to write a csh script and then execute it
something like

```
set fout [open ./sedShell.sh w]
puts $fout "#/bin/csh\n"

for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $moduleList]} {incr i} {
    set mTarget [lindex $moduleList $i]    
    set mReplace [lindex $moduleReplaceList $i]
    set tmp ""
    puts $fout [append tmp "sed -i 's/" $mTarget "/" $mReplace "/g' " 
    $verilog_new ]   
}
close $fout
exec chmod 755 sedShell.sh
exec sedShell.sh
exec /bin/rm -f sedShell.sh
```

it can correctly do what i want 
but i don't know why i can not do the same thing in tcl

Comment: try `""` instead of `{}`

Comment: `csh` is a particularly horrible choice for writing a shell script.

Comment: Take care that `$mTarget` and `$mReplace` do not contain slashes, or else you'll break sed. If you're not 100% certain of the contents of those variables, you might want to do `regsub -all / $mTarget {\/} mTarget` and the same with the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You want to build your sed command inside quotes because you're making Tcl-level substitutions within it (subject to a few minor provisos):

```
exec sed -i "s/$mTarget/$mReplace/g" $verilog_new
```

You can also build the sed script in any number of other ways, e.g., with `format` or `string map`:

```
set script [format {s/%s/%s/g} $mTarget $mReplace]
exec sed -i $script $verilog_new
```

```
set script [string map [list TGT $mTarget RPL $mReplace] {s/TGT/RPL/g}]
exec sed -i $script $verilog_new
```

The provisos above? The script *must not* end up looking like one of the redirections listed on the [`exec` manual page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm). Fortunately, if you have one of those then you can instead write your script to a temporary file and use that:

```
set f [file tempfile sedscript]
puts $f "s/$mTarget/$mReplace/g"
close $f
exec sed -i -f $sedscript $verilog_new
file delete $sedscript
```

Answer (score 1):

The following ought to work (can't test it for lack of standalone `sed`; Donal's caveats regarding the `exec` command line apply):

```
foreach mTarget $moduleList mReplace $moduleReplaceList {
    exec sed -i s/$mTarget/$mReplace/g $verilog_new 
}
```

A pure-Tcl variant:

```
package require fileutil

proc replace {froms tos contents} {
    foreach from $froms to $tos {
        regsub -all $from $contents $to contents
    }
    return $contents
}

::fileutil::updateInPlace $verilog_new [list replace $moduleList $moduleReplaceList]
```

Documentation:
[exec](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm),
[fileutil (package)](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm),
[package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[regsub](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm),
[return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm)